# Firebase UI 3.0.0: Retrieve data to recycle view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone help me to retrieve data from the node "foods" and put it in the `RecyclerView`. These are the file I've been working on but it turns out to be an empty list. I have viewed a tutorial on Internet but most of them were with an older version of Firebase. Recently, Firebase UI has been updated and the data binding process has changed to their new `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` structure

This is my database structure:

```
"foods" : {
"AntipastoSalad" : {
  "duration" : "30",
  "img" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mealplanner-ec8ca.appspot.com/o/res%2Fsalad.jpg?alt=media&token=257d4392-8a1f-4fb7-84b5-b63abb4643f4",
  "name" : "Antipasto salad",
  "type" : "Salad"
},
```

This is my activity:

```
    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private Query query;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Meal> options;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list_row);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("foods");

        //Recycle View
        mRecycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.meal_items);
        mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://mealplanner-ec8ca.firebaseio.com/foods/AntipastoSalad");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Meal>()
                .setQuery(query, Meal.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Meal, FoodListRowActivity.MealRowHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Meal, FoodListRowActivity.MealRowHolder>(
                options) {
            @Override
            public FoodListRowActivity.MealRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.food_row, parent, false);
                return new FoodListRowActivity.MealRowHolder(v);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(FoodListRowActivity.MealRowHolder holder, int position, Meal current) {
                holder.setTitle(current.getName());
                String duration = current.getDuration() + "min";
                holder.setDuration(duration);
            }
        };

        //Populate Item into Adapter
        mRecycleView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        mRecycleView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecycleViewItemClickListener(this, mRecycleView, new RecycleViewItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent viewMeal = new Intent(FoodListRowActivity.this, CookingInstructionActivity.class);
                startActivity(viewMeal);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                //TODO: DELETE
            }
        }));
    }

    public static class MealRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public MealRowHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView foodTitle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_foodList_name);
            foodTitle.setText(title);
        }


        public void setDuration(String title) {
            TextView foodDuration = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_foodList_calories);
            foodDuration.setText(title);
        }
    }
}
```

and class structure:

```
public class Meal{

private String img;
private String duration;
private String name;
private String instruction;

public Meal(){

}

public Meal (String img, String duration, String name, String instruction){
    this.img = img;
    this.name = name;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.instruction = instruction;
}

public void update(String duration, String name, String instruction)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.instruction = instruction;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public String getInstruction() {
    return instruction;
}

public String getImg(){return img;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` specified in the `setQuery()` method should be a reference to the root of the list you want to show in the `RecyclerView`, so like this:

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("foods");
```

You also need to call `startListening()` on the adapter to instruct it to start retrieving data from the database.

From the [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter lifecycle documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle):

> The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.
>
> ```
> @Override protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     adapter.startListening();
> }
> ```
>
> Similarly, the `stopListening()` call removes the event listener and all data in the adapter. Call this method when the containing `Activity` or `Fragment` stops:
>
> ```
> @Override protected void onStop() {
>     super.onStop();
>     adapter.stopListening();
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm retrieving my data in recyclerview using Firebase UI:

```
 private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TaskPOJO, TaskViewHolder> adapter;
 private void loadTasks() {


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        tasks = database.getReference("Tasks");
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TaskPOJO, TaskViewHolder>(TaskPOJO.class, R.layout.task_item, TaskViewHolder.class, tasks) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, final TaskPOJO model, int position) {


                Log.wtf("valueTEst", "populateViewHolder: "+model.toString() );
                Log.wtf("TEstScript1", "populateViewHolder: "+model.getTitle() );
                viewHolder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.desc.setText(model.getDescripttion()+"\n");
                viewHolder.remaining.setText(model.getRemaining()+"/"+model.getPoint());
                viewHolder.points.setText("Points "+model.getRemaining());
                Glide.with(viewHolder.title.getContext())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.image);


                viewHolder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" /*+ model.getTitle()*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent TaskPOJODetail = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
                        TaskPOJODetail.putExtra("value","detail");
                        TaskPOJODetail.putExtra("taskId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(TaskPOJODetail);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerViewTasks.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

this is my firebase structure :

[image: structure in firebase]

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that this was the old version of Firebase UI :(

Answer (score 0):

Please override `getItemCount()` method of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }
```

[Reference.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java)

Comment: It's seem that's wasnt problem. The app just crash and print java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0. But thank for your help.